# PowerMockito. Проблемы с запуском теста со статичным методом

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

Есть обычный класс:

```
class UsualClass {

    fun getTestedString(): String {
        return StaticClass.getTestedString()
    }
}
```

И есть класс со статичным методом:

```
object StaticClass {

    fun getStaticString(): String {
        return "Not tested string"
    }
}
```

Код класса с тестом:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticClass::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val usualClass = UsualClass()
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass::class.java)        
        PowerMockito.`when`(StaticClass.getStaticString())
            .thenReturn("Tested string")
        System.out.println(usualClass.getTestedString())
    }
}
```

При попытке запустить тест, он падает с ошибкой:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, проблема в том, что в kotlin все классы и методы по дефолту final. Попробуйте изменить моккируемые классы и методы на open